# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "i18n":

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, redmine, redmine-plugins

im a noob. i need help.

im trying to install Redmine CRM plugin however im getting an error when i run this:

```
bundle install --without development test
```

it says:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "i18n":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.2.0) ruby depends on
      railties (= 4.2.0) ruby depends on
        activesupport (= 4.2.0) ruby depends on
          i18n (~> 0.7) ruby

    money (~> 5.1.0) ruby depends on
      i18n (~> 0.6.0) ruby
```

Comment: Do you want to install Redmine CRM plugin?

Comment: yes im trying to install Redmine CRM plugin

Comment: Good questions always mention all relevant software version numbers involved! Please update

Answer (score 2):

Redmine CRM plugin has to be upgraded to newer versions of redmine in parallel. I recommend to upgrade redmine first (with an empty plugins directory) and then add the redminecrm plugins and upgrade them too.

Redmine CRM Plugin 4.0.3 is compatible with Redmine 2.6-3.1
Older versions of the Redmine CRM Plugin installed on Redmine 3.1 result in the error you posted.

Answer (score 0):

In your Gemfile, manually specify I18n gem like

```
gem 'I18n', '~0.6.0'
```

Comment: sorry i get a bit confused. which Gemfile?

here is the path of my redmine:     /var/www/redmine

and the path of the plugin im trying to install: /var/www/redmine/plugins/redmine_contacts/

both has Gemfile

Comment: In your plugin Gemfile

Comment: i added 'gem 'I18n', '~0.6.0'

but i get an error **There was an error in your Gemfile, and Bundler cannot continue.**